# Add Searchable dropdown menu in odoo using js and python

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-8

I am new to odd-python and I have to create a dropdown with search input box in one of my template, but I am not sure how to create or find relatable source code.

So far I was able to do below code

```
<div>
    <label for="html">
        <h3>
            <div style="color:white;">Part Number </div>
        </h3>
    </label>
    <select data-type="search" class="product_select" data-search="true">
        <t t-foreach="widget.pro_name" t-as="partner">
            <option t-att-value="partner['id']" widget="domain" options="{'model': 'model_name'}">
                <h3>
                    <t t-esc="partner['name']" />
                </h3>
            </option>
        </t>
    </select>
</div>
```

Even after setting `data-search="true"` in select element, Its still not showing input type, can anyone please help me or guide for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Datalists](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/form-control/#datalists), it is similar to `<select>` elements

```
<label for="part_number" class="form-label">Part Number</label>
<input class="form-control" list="PartNumberOptions" id="part_number" placeholder="Type to search..."/>
<datalist id="PartNumberOptions">

</datalist>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I have id and label both are different so not understand how to use in datalist. So i am trying same thing in select element